# iOS Draw a chevron pattern by finger slide

Tags: ios, iphone, drawing, core-graphics

I am trying to draw a **chevron** pattern (which is basically just a zig-zag line) by dragging my finger in a drawing canvas. So the line goes up Y amount then down Y amount and repeat. I am wondering the best way to do this. So far I am creating 1 section in the wave and then adding it to a mutable path and then displaying the new path. I would really like for it to work like the way the zig-zag is drawn here: [seamless lite](http://www.colourlovers.com/seamless) Here's my code. There will obviously be parts missing but they are there elsewhere in order for the drawing to be displayed.

What is happening now is it will draw part of the zig-zag when I reach the specific distance value by sliding my finger from left to right. It will flash the drawing and then disappear. At this point I want the lines to stay there so I can keep adding onto the zig-zag pattern for whatever distance I choose. If you continue sliding your finger it will appear again after reaching that same distance and then disappear right after leaving that value.

Main draw:

```
- (void)draw
{
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// set the line properties
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
CGContextSetAlpha(context, self.lineAlpha);

CGContextAddPath(context, [self drawChevronFromOrigin:CGPointMake(self.firstPoint.x, self.firstPoint.y)]);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

}
```

Draw zig-zag and return new path:

```
- (CGMutablePathRef)drawChevronFromOrigin:(CGPoint)origin
{
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, origin.x, origin.y);

if (fmodf(self.lastPoint.x - origin.x, 50) == 0)
{
    // Add new chevron wave to specific point
    CGPathAddPath(path, nil, [self drawChevronWaveToPoint:CGPointMake(self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y)]);
}


return path;
}
```

How each zig-zag is drawn:

```
- (CGMutablePathRef)drawChevronWaveToPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
// Creates one wave in the chevron pattern
CGMutablePathRef chevronWave = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(chevronWave, nil, point.x, point.y);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(chevronWave, nil, point.x + 25, point.y+25);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(chevronWave, nil, point.x + 50, point.y-25);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(chevronWave, nil, point.x + 75, point.y+25);

return chevronWave;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you provide more context as to what you feel is wrong with your code?  You didn't describe what it does that isn't to your liking.

Comment: @jordan Did you find any solution, if yes please post answer and accept it. I am also searching for your approach in CG way. Thanks

Comment: We are drawing patterns a different way now instead of using your finger to interactivity draw it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I would approach this in a different way than using Core Graphics. Assuming that the zig-zag extends in a straight line, you can create a view with a repeating pattern image as it's background and then change the width of that as the finger moves to the left or right. You can do it with an angle as well in which case you would rotate the view with a transform (not shown here).

(I'll be drawing a squiggled line because I like squiggles more than zig-zags)

In an image editor, create a single zig-zag (or in my case squiggle), it could looks something like this. Just make sure that the left and right edges are mirrored so that it becomes a nice patter when repeated.

[image] 
[image]

Then in code, you can create a pattern *color* like this

```
UIColor *pattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"squiggle.png"]];
```

For the actual interaction (tapping and then dragging to draw the squiggle, I'm using a pan gesture recognizer, created like this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = 
    [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                            action:@selector(userDidPan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

To make the pan code easier I created a property for the current squiggle and the point that the pan started at

```
@property (nonatomic, weak)   UIView *currentSquiggleView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint startLocation;
```

The pan gesture code has 3 parts to it: begin, change and end. When the pan begins, I create a new squiggle view with the same height as my image but with no width and place it at the location of the finger. As the finger moves I get and the pan changes I update the width of the current squiggle so that it grows. Not that panning to the left may cause a negative width, in which case the view has to move as well. Finally when the pan ends, I set the current squiggle to nil so that I can no longer modify it. The entire pan code looks like this:

```
- (void)userDidPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    switch (pan.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan: {
            // Create a new squiggle
            UIColor *pattern = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"squiggle.png"]];

            CGPoint panLocation = [pan locationInView:self.view];

            CGRect startRect = CGRectMake(panLocation.x,
                                          panLocation.y,
                                          0,   // no width to begin with
                                          24); // my squiggle image is 24px high
            UIView *squiggle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:startRect];
            squiggle.backgroundColor = pattern;
            [self.view addSubview:squiggle];

            self.startLocation = panLocation;
            self.currentSquiggleView = squiggle;

        } break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            // Change the width of the squiggle
            CGRect previousFrame = self.currentSquiggleView.frame;

            CGPoint panMovement = [pan translationInView:self.view];

            // when panning to the right, increase the width.
            // when panning to the left, increase the width and move the view to the left
            CGRect newFrame = previousFrame;
            newFrame.size.width = fabs(panMovement.x);
            if (panMovement.x < 0) {
                newFrame.origin.x = self.startLocation.x + panMovement.x;
            }

            // standardize the rect before assigning since a left pan could give a negative width
            self.currentSquiggleView.frame = CGRectStandardize(newFrame);

        } break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            // Stop referencing this squiggle so that we don't modify it anymore
            self.currentSquiggleView = nil;
        } break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And the squiggly result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: That's a really neat approach thanks for sharing. Unfortunately I have to find a way to do it in CG because it will need to scale up and down. Thanks for taking the time to show this to me though, very nice!

Comment: If you need to scale it, could you do with creating zig-zag images in code on the fly for the scale that you need?

Comment: Another reason I need this in CG is because I am going to need the individual points that make up the line so I can export that data.

Comment: Ok, so it's not just about dragging your finder to underline something in the UI?

Comment: No, it is for drawing shapes/patterns on a canvas